# Expected value from test problem matches my value, but test fails

Tags: python

Would anybody happen to know if there is something missing to make this module pass? My output is exactly the same as the expected output.

> Define a function `pyramid_volume` with parameters `base_length`, `base_width`, and `pyramid_height`, that returns the volume of a pyramid with a rectangular base.
>
> Sample output with inputs: `pyramid_volume( 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 ) =>` **`9.45`**
>
> Relevant geometry equations:
>
> - `Volume = base area x height x 1/3`
> - `Base area = base length x base width.`

here is my code, as well as a picture of the entire module.

```
    def pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
        base_area = base_length * base_width
        volume = (base_area * pyramid_height) / 3
        return '%.2f' % volume
    
    length = float(input()) # I cannot change from here down
    width = float(input())
    height = float(input())
    print('Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is:', pyramid_volume(length, width, height))
```

[image]

Comment: `return '%.2f' % volume` <-- I'm pretty sure this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Have you tried only `return volume` and `print(pyramid_volume(...))`? Where do the instructions say to return strings or print some description (with hard-coded numbers rather than your inputs)?

Comment: You are returning a string, but you should be returning a number (just write `return volume`). Plus, everything outside the function is useless. The test asks you to `define a function` and that's it, you can delete everything after the `return` line